# Create a sy.BaseDataset from dataloader

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, pysyft

I have an image dataset so I load it with pytorch in this manner:

```
training_dataset = datasets.ImageFolder(path)
train_set = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(training_dataset)
```

my `train_set` is a `torch.dataloader.DataLoader` however I want to get `sy.BaseDataset` [more details](https://pysyftbenardi.readthedocs.io/en/add_sphinx_docs/api/syft/frameworks/torch/fl/dataset/index.html#syft.frameworks.torch.fl.dataset.BaseDataset)
So please how can I transfrom my dataset knowing that
`dataset = sy.BaseDataset(data, target)`
So how extracting data and target knowing that the name of directory is the label(target) ?

Thanks

Comment: What is `BaseDataset`?